# How can readline be told not to erase externally supplied prompt?

Tags: c, ghostscript, readline

I'm attempting to add readline support to ghostscript (casperscript), and it seems to be working except for one problem: when one or more characters is typed, and I backspace over them, the line is entirely erased including the prompt, which is supplied by ghostscript *before* gp_readline is called. I already found and added `rl_already_prompted = (int)true`, but the documentation says for it to work properly, the prompt text must still be supplied as the arg to `readline`, and that looks like it will require a lot of ugliness, I was trying to avoid.

Any ideas on grabbing the prompt from the terminal, or another more elegant approach? https://github.com/jcomeauictx/casperscript/commit/d5492b72b7515971e5fa2cc9770c75ef7f88330d

Comment: If it were possible to get this from the terminal, `readline()` would do that so you wouldn't have to supply it as an explicit argument.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using CPR. Not cardio-pulmonary resuscitation, but the ANSI escape sequence that reports cursor position; I then create a prompt of all dots except for a final ">", like a Python continuation prompt. In practice, it hasn't yet been displayed, but it prevents backspacing over the existing prompt, which is what I wanted. https://github.com/jcomeauictx/casperscript/commit/a94ddfe37e89ae223cc91401250857d26061b156